# Is Masterthought report threadsafe?

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline, cucumber, maven-plugin

I tried to parallelize maven build from Jenkins, but thats giving below error

```
[[1;33mWARNING[m] *****************************************************************
[[1;33mWARNING[m] * Your build is requesting parallel execution, but project      *
[[1;33mWARNING[m] * contains the following plugin(s) that have goals not marked   *
[[1;33mWARNING[m] * as @threadSafe to support parallel building.                  *
[[1;33mWARNING[m] * While this /may/ work fine, please look for plugin updates    *
[[1;33mWARNING[m] * and/or request plugins be made thread-safe.                   *
[[1;33mWARNING[m] * If reporting an issue, report it against the plugin in        *
[[1;33mWARNING[m] * question, not against maven-core                              *
[[1;33mWARNING[m] *****************************************************************
[[1;33mWARNING[m] The following plugins are not marked @threadSafe in XXXXXXXXXXXXX:
[[1;33mWARNING[m] net.masterthought:maven-cucumber-reporting:5.7.0
[[1;33mWARNING[m] Enable debug to see more precisely which goals are not marked @threadSafe.
[[1;33mWARNING[m] *****************************************************************
```

Is masterthought cucumber reporting thread safe ? and is there any way i could parallelize the build ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version `5.7.0` is not marked by author as `threadSafe`.

Simply is such case the better way is ask on plugin [issues](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/maven-cucumber-reporting/issues) management list.